# Actualizar imagen cropperjs

Tags: javascript, html, imagen

Estoy tratando de recotar una imagen antes de subirla, para esto me apoyo en [Cropperjs](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs). El problema que me encuentro es que cuando seleccionas una imagen la primera carga sin problema, pero si por el motivo que sea vuelves a seleccionar otra imagen diferente, Cropper mantiene siempre la primera imagen que seleccionas en el `input` dejo un ejemplo donde reproducir lo que sucede:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ejemplo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.5/cropper.css" integrity="sha256-x8iLuq/BLgVhgqscHiKrBZFP60kV2Xuilmpqy7kD/vI=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="inputImage" name="image" accept="image/*">

    <div>
      <img id="img">
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.5/cropper.js" integrity="sha256-U/8sUxL62BDCJvl8Dmu1uuTtKilSrHytsP3XfgCJZwo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
    const inputImage = document.getElementById('inputImage');
    const img = document.getElementById('img');

    inputImage.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        let files = e.target.files;
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);

        new Cropper(img, {
            aspectRatio: 4/3,
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente ya he podido encontrar una solución, aun que antes ya habia probado algo similar y no me funciono, basicamente la idea es comprobar si `img.src` tiene algun valor, si no tiene creo el Cropper en caso contrario destruyo el cropper y utilizo replace para paserle la nueva imagen.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>ejemplo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.5/cropper.css" integrity="sha256-x8iLuq/BLgVhgqscHiKrBZFP60kV2Xuilmpqy7kD/vI=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="inputImage" name="image" accept="image/*">

    <div>
      <img id="img">
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.5/cropper.js" integrity="sha256-U/8sUxL62BDCJvl8Dmu1uuTtKilSrHytsP3XfgCJZwo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
    const inputImage = document.getElementById('inputImage');
    const img = document.getElementById('img');
    var crop = null;

    inputImage.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        let files = e.target.files;

        if (img.src) {
            img.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
            crop.destroy();
            crop.replace(img.src);
        } else {
            img.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
            crop = new Cropper(img, {
                aspectRatio: 4/3,
            });
        }

    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```